# Prove that the Hilbert Cube is complete (Stuck on proof)

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am undergraduate student, this is my first class on "real analysis" I don't know about compactness yet. This comes from chapter 7 of NL Carothers "Principles of Analysis."

> The Hilbert cube $H^{\infty}$is the collection of all real sequences
>   $x=(x_{n})$ with $|x_{n}|\leq1$ for all $n=1,2,...$. Consider the
>   metric space $(H^{\infty},d)$ where $d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_{n}-y_{n}|}{2^{-n}}$.

Here is my attempt:

> To prove that the Hilbert cube is complete with the metric $d$ above
>   it is sufficient to show that every infinite, totally bounded subset
>   of $H^{\infty}$ has a limit point in $H^{\infty}.$ Let $S$ be an
>   infinite, totally bounded subset of $H^{\infty}$. Such a set exists
>   since the collection of all real sequences $x=x_{n}$ with $|x_{n}|\leq1$
>   and is isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. $A$ contains a Cauchy
>   sequence $(x_{n})$ since $A$ is totally bounded (recall: every sequence
>   has a Cauchy subsequence). This sequence is comprised of distinct
>   points, that is $x_{n}\neq x_{m}$ when $n\neq m.$ Set $A_{n}=\{x_{k}:k\geq n\}.$
>   Then we have that $A\supset A_{1}\supset A_{2}\supset...$. Each $A_{n}$
>   is nonempty and $diam(A_{n})\rightarrow0.$ But clearly $cl(A_{n})\supset cl(A_{n+1})\neq\emptyset$ for each $n$ and $diam(cl(A_{n}))=diam(A_{n})\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
>   Therefore there is an $x\in\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}cl(A_{n})\neq\emptyset.$
>   Now since $x_{n}\in A_{n}\implies d(x_{n},x)\leq diam(cl(A_{n}))\rightarrow0.$
>   That is $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ and so $x$ is a limit point of $A.$

I am really so lost though. I wrote this by following along with the proof in NL Carothers chapter 7 on statements equivalent to saying a metric space $(M,d)$ is complete. I just don't know how I know that $A$ exists. I am so stuck there.

I just "feel" like its probably true that the collection of all real sequences $x=x_{n}$ with $|x_{n}|\leq1$ is isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. I actually don't know this, but intuitively in my head it makes since. And if that's true I also feel like it's probably also true that $A$ exists. But this isn't really "rigorous" it's just a hunch on top of another hunch...

Comment: Did you not use in the existence of the intersection point $x$ the completeness of the set that you just wanted to show? -- The surrounding Banach space is complete, you only need to show that the Hilbert cube is a closed subset, which it is as intersection of closed subsets ${x:|x_n|≤1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what is the surrounding Banach space? Why is the intersection of closed subsets $x:|x_n| \leq 1$

Comment: The metric $d$ is a norm, the space of all sequences $x$ with $d(0,x)<\infty$ is a Banach space isomorphic to $\ell^1$. $$\{x|\forall n:|x_n|\le 1\}=\bigcap_n\{x||x_n|\le 1\}.$$